# How to put a "-" in string.xml file

Tags: android, string

I need to be able to put a "-" in the string inside my `strings.xml` file.

My problem is that when I am putting my string which is `"1261eba2-9d8c-11e1-93e3-40409e0f44a1"`, eclipse yells:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Replace "-" with an "en dash" character (–, 
>        &;#8211;)

How can I fix this?

Comment: where exactly do you need that value? Is it a tag, a tag value or an attribute value?

Comment: replace "-" with "\-"

Answer (score 124, accepted):

So, when you read the error message, your answer will be that
you have to replace `-` with `&#8211;`. Then it should work fine =)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Comment: This is OK when you just want to display the string to the user. The user can't really tell that you are "cheating" with a similar looking unicode character. If you just want to use the regular dash see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10895509/78234

Comment: I think that code is for endash, not a regular hyphen.

Comment: Ya that's an en-dash not a hyphen https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html

Answer (score 88):

The other answers are OK for when you want to display the string to the user. The user can't really tell the difference between a "real" dash and the unicode trickery.
But, if you really must have the dash (e.g. because that string is used as a password somewhere, or as a url key for an API) then you can just use this format:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <string name="EVA_API_KEY">3c42b725-5e20-41c8-982f-dee40be8a05b</string>
</resources>
```

The warning will be removed and the string can be read using the regular:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.EVA_API_KEY);
```

Comment: One tip: you might want to put the tools:ignore="TypographyDashes" part into just those <string> tags that really need the real dash.

Comment: For some reason it only worked for me when I put the ignore on the string i'm using. Thanks for the answer I found out it was the wrong dash, but how to get it to work wasn't as straightforward.

Comment: I was trying to launch the phone dialer for 9-1-1 and your answer was the key for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Use **back slash** ( \ ) in front of every special character.  like me\&android.

This called escape character. ( \ )

Comment: I think you mean add the escape character: "\" before every special character.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character escape character is backslash - "\" not forward slash - "/"

Comment: check my answer now. this is back slash (\).

Comment: when im using what you all are saing its removing the "-" char...  what im getting is: 1261eba29d8c11e193e340409e0f44a1 insted of 1261eba2-9d8c-11e1-93e3-40409e0f44a1...

Answer (score 5):

For hyphen use (&#45) (-)...

```
<string name="abc">Welcome &#45; Bro...</string>
```

and For more symbol use below link

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Enjoy...

Answer (score 4):

> The dash is a punctuation mark that is similar to a hyphen or minus sign, but differs from both of these symbols primarily in length and function. The most common versions of the dash are the en dash (–) and the em dash (—), named for the length of a typeface's lower-case n and upper-case M respectively.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)

Just replace `-` with `–` because when you type a dash on the keyboard, XML reads dash as minus, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have this:

```
<string name="test1">1261eba2-9d8c-11e1-93e3-40409e0f44a1</string>
```

But you need either one of these:

```
<string name="test2">1261eba2&#8211;9d8c&#8211;11e1&#8211;93e3&#8211;40409e0f44a1</string>
<string name="test3">1261eba2–9d8c–11e1–93e3–40409e0f44a1</string>
```

In the second one the - is replaced by a –. It's hard to tell the difference visually.

Comment: Be careful though: if you change these symbols in a URL it might stop working (mine did).

Comment: I want to replace a short dash symbol (n-dash) with an escaped sequence.  But `&#8211;` looks like its the escape sequence for the long dash symbol (m-dash).

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix shortcut in Eclipse is `Ctrl` + `1` by default and in Android Studio is `Alt` + `Enter` by default.