# How to put a “-” in string.xml file, but without escaping

Tags: android

I have a configuration.xml file which I hold all the (yep, you guessed it!).. configuration strings and values and stuff.

One of those values is a string which is an oauth client id, and it has a hyphen..

```
<string name="server_clientid">5467656-blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```

Now I get the warning message..

```
Replace "-" with an "en dash" character (–, &#8211;) ?
```

Ok fair enough, but if I escape with this then the client id is not valid when I fetch it within the app. I can't use & #8211; basically. How do I get around this?

Comment: This is warning.. you can use this string..

Comment: What prevents you from parsing the en dash when reading the UUID?

Comment: duplicate of [How to put a "-" in string.xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578551/how-to-put-a-in-string-xml-file). You will get your answer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wrap your values in

```
<![CDATA[ ]]>
```

which stops the parser from parsing the contents. E.g.

```
<string name="server_clientid"><![CDATA[ 5467656-blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com ]]></string>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `<![CDATA[ ]]> ` goes inside the `string` tag.

Answer (score 7):

You can also suppress the lint warning (which is false since the dash is not used in a typographical context):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

 ...

<string name="server_clientid" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">5467656-blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The "n dash" (–, –) and the "m dash" (—, —)
>   characters are used for ranges (n dash) and breaks (m dash). Using
>   these instead of plain hyphens can make text easier to read and your
>   application will look more polished.

Replace smaller "**-**" with bigger "**–**". You are good to go.