# String xml to write "<"

Tags: android, xml, string

How to put a “<” in string.xml file i ve been searching for a solution for this problem but i cant any and im getting an error when i just put a simple < in the string file any ideas i saw this question but its not the same with mu problem [How to put a "-" in string.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578551/how-to-put-a-in-string-xml-file)

here is my code

```
<string name="sp"> SP </string>
<string name="p1"> P1 </string>
<string name="p2"> P2 </string>
<string name="p3"> P3 </string>
<string name="p4"> P4 </string>
<string name="dialogprevious"> < </string> -- error here
<string name="dialognext"> > </string>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write `<` as entity-escaped `&lt;` (mnemonic: lt as in less than).

Similarly `>` as `&gt;` (greater than).

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for >

Also, check this out : [here](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0)

Answer (score 0):

1) for less than(<), use `&lt;`

2) for greateh than(>), use `&gt;`