# How to resolve an incorrect string value error (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, xml, utf-8

I have some documents, formatted in XML. I want to store their contents (raw text, formatting preserved) in cells in an SQL table, as `LONGTEXT`, so that I can simply grab the value of a cell and load it in a webpage later. I am doing this via MySQL Workbench.

However, when I try to apply the additions to my table, I get error **1366: Incorrect string value: `\xE2\x80\xAF1, ...`**

I tried changing the character set to `utf-8-general-ci` and `cp1251`, but I keep getting the same errors.

Also, I searched the XML file for the string `\xE2\x80\xAF1`, but it's not even in the file.

Does anybody know what this string is?

The XML file is only 219KB so I think it should (very) easily fit in a `LONGTEXT` entry.

Does XML make use of any characters that could cause this error?

Am I missing another cause of the error?

Comment: You probably won't see literal `\xE2` in your file. That's a text representation of a binary value. Is your XML UTF-8 clean? Is your column *and* connection UTF-8?

Comment: Possible duplicate; consider checking this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1168099/6381711) for a quick resolution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not a literal text but points to [NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm).

With UTF-8 simple characters are coded as one byte, other characters need two bytes.

And there are some characters which need three bytes. These characters tend to lead to such errors.

Find a related question here: [freebcp: "Unicode data is odd byte size for column. Should be even byte size"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38984053/5089204)

Comment: The link is irrelevant since it is talking about SQL Server, not MySQL.  As you say, `E280AF` is a _utf8_ character.  _Unicode_ would encode it as hex `202F`.  Also, utf8 _characters_ can be a big as 4 _bytes_.  In MySQL, that requires `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Most of Asia needs 3-byte utf8; Chinese needs some 4-byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- specify utf8 (or utf8mb4) for the connection established from your client (Workbench).
- declare the column in question to be `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).